# Can't get Web.py and jQuery to work out an AJAX GET request (it turns to an OPTIONS request instead)

Tags: python, ajax, jquery, web, web.py

I am trying to get (the latest) Web.py and AJAX to play nice with each other, but so far I haven't had much luck.

Long story short, I am running both the server-side (Web.py) and the client side (Javascript) on my local development computer, but somehow all my AJAX GET requests are showing up as OPTION requests. From what I've read, this is typical is cases of cross domain requests, but since I'm running this on localhost I am not sure what's going on.

Here's the server-side code:

```
import web
import json

def make_text(string):
    return string

urls = ('/', 'mainScreen',
    '/update', 'update'
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())

global content
content = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}

def getPayload():
    return content

class mainScreen:

    def GET(self):
        web.header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        web.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        web.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
        return getPayload()

    def OPTIONS(self):
        web.header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        web.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        web.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
        return getPayload()

class update:
    def POST(self):
        global content
        content = web.input(_method='post')
        return "DONE."


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Here's the client-side code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>WTF</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function dial()
            {
                console.log("Fire in the hole!");

                $.ajax({
                     url: 'http://0.0.0.0:8080',
                     contentType: 'application/jsonp',
                     timeout : 5000,
                     cache: false,
                     success: function (data) {
                        console.log('[ajax] Connection successful! ' + JSON.stringify(data));
                    },
                    error:function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR) + ' ' + textStatus +'  '+errorThrown );
                    }
                });

                console.log("Done.");
            }


            $(function() {
                dial();
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is Firebug's output:

> Fire in the hole!           index.html (line 9) DONE.
>   index.html (line 24) [ajax] Connection successful! ""
>   index.html (line 17)

Notice that the "" indicate that the request got empty data.

This is what Firebug's network panel shows:

[image: Firebug's network panel, showing the request]

If i open the page that Firebug indicates the data's there alright but if I, quite simply open `http://0.0.0.0:8080/` on any browser, the data is displayed as expected! What is happening here?

Finally, here's Web.py's log:

```
    hal@ubuntu:~/Desktop/tut$ python app.py
    http://0.0.0.0:8080/
    127.0.0.1:43796 - - [26/Jul/2013 11:14:59] "HTTP/1.1 OPTIONS /" - 200 OK
```

I'm coding in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS by the way.

PS: I also tried changing the response header inside Web.py to:

```
web.header('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
```

but it didn't work.

PS2: Changing the server address on the client-side script to "127.0.0.1:8080" or "localhost:8080" didn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nailed it.

The issue was on the client-side code. I remove the contentType from the request itself and it worked perfectly.